# Ng show for settings page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on a settings page for a planning poker app I am developing. What I would like to have happen is to have the rest of the settings only visible if "become scrum master is checked". Ive looked at ng-show and am not quite sure how it works, here is my attempt but it doesnt work as everything is still visible

```
 <section class="mainbar" ng-controller="gameSetupController">
<section class="matter">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Create Game</h3>
        <form class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="project-selector">Project</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="project-selector" ng-model="gameContext.project" ng-options="p.name for p in projects"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="scrum-master-checkbox">Become Scrum Master</label>
                <input id="scrum-master-checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="gameContext.isScrumMaster" />
            </div>
            <div id="scrum-master-options" ng-model="scrum-master-options" ng show="scrum-master-options">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Card Options</label>
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="gameContext.cardType" value="fibonacci" />Fibonacci (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144)
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="gameContext.cardType" value="modified" /> Modified Fibonacci (.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20, 40, 100)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Point Suggestion Method</label>
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="gameContext.pointSelectionMethod" value="Average3" />Take average if all votes are within three cards
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="gameContext.pointSelectionMethod" value="Mode" />Take the card selected most often by players
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="gameContext.pointSelectionMethod" value="Average" /> Take average of all votes
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="gameContext.pointSelectionMethod" value="None" />Do not suggest story points
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="allowReselectCard">Allow Cards To Be Reselected</label>
                    <input id="allowReselectCard" type="checkbox" ng-model="gameContext.allowReselectCard" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="{{href()}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-disabled="gameContext.project.id === undefined" title="{{ gameContext.project.id === undefined ? 'Please select a project' : 'Join the ' + gameContext.project.name + ' game' }}">Join Game</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `ng-show` to `gameContext.isScrumMaster` instead because that's the model updated by the checkbox.  Also, remove the `ng-model` from the containing div because it only applies to inputs, selects, textareas, and custom form controls.

```
<div id="scrum-master-options" ng-show="gameContext.isScrumMaster">
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: Ok i did that, and the other options are now hidden but when i click the become scrum master check box the other options are still hidden

Comment: im having difficulty making it function on fiddle. Basically before i added your suggestion, there were options such as allow reselect card, point selection method , card options etc, i wanted them to be hidden unless you check become scrum master, i added your suggestion and now the other options dont display which is what i wanted except, i wanted them to display if the box is checked and currently they do not display when become scrum master is checked

Comment: You need to use ngShow only on the options you want hidden unless `scrumMaster=true`, don't use it on the whole DIV.  Do it on the individual controls themselves to gain more finegrained control.